# Accessing bottle app using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName ubuntu.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess kenobi user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/kenobi/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/kenobi>
        WSGIProcessGroup kenobi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**app.wsgi**

```
import os, sys

# Change working directory so relative paths (and template lookup) work again
sys.path.append('/var/www/kenobi')
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print sys.path


import server
print "launching..."
application = server.launch()
print "done"
```

**server.py (script that implements rest api's using bottle framework)**

```
@route('/helloworld', method='GET')
def get_service_host_list():
    return("hello world")

def launch():
    print "attaching to server"
    run(host="192.168.45.111", port="8085", debug=True)
    #application = bottle.default_app()
```

So the above code works fine except that it uses two ports -
8081 used by mod_wsgi to launch server.py and
8085 port on which server.py listens

What changes do I need to make in server.py so that only port 8081 is used?
I already tried using application = bottle.default_app() but I get "500 Internal Server Error" with following error in apache2 error.log, whenever I call "helloworld" api:

```
[Sat Aug 23 12:05:17 2014] [error] launching...
[Sat Aug 23 12:05:17 2014] [error] attaching to server
[Sat Aug 23 12:05:17 2014] [error] done
[Sat Aug 23 12:05:17 2014] [error] [client 192.168.42.135] mod_wsgi (pid=35700):     Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/kenobi/app.wsgi'.
[Sat Aug 23 12:05:17 2014] [error] [client 192.168.42.135] TypeError: 'NoneType' object     is not callable
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops had to do following changes to get this thing working:
Change def launch() in server.py to

```
print "attaching to server"
application = bottle.default_app()
```

Replace following in app.wsgi FROM

```
import server
print "launching..."
application = server.launch()
print "done"
```

TO

```
print "launching..."
from server import application
print "done"
```

Comment: That still looks suspicious as 'application' would only be set in the local stack of the launch() function and not at global scope, and even then, that wouldn't happen since launch() is now not called based on what you are showing. The docs at  http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#apache-mod-wsgi do not show a launch() function at all and set application at global scope. So just follow the docs.

Comment: Thanks Graham for pointing that out. It was a typo. I got rid of the launch function and call default_app() directly (as seen in the edited post above)